# A templated class is larger than non-template class using same type?

Tags: c++, templates

I was once asked a trick question at a job interview: does a templated class take more memory than another class which is identical but not templated? My answer was no, but the fact that he asked the question means there's probably a case where there is. Or, he really wanted to screw with me. What would be a case where a templated class would take more memory?

Comment: I suspect the fact that he asked the question indicates there are people who *think* a class template takes more memory than a non-template class.

Comment: no, it isn't. it takes exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, `class template` take more memory than a normal class, but that's in source file because more text is required.

Comment: Does "identical but not templated" mean the other class is just the templated class with the template parameters spelled out? Or does it mean the non-templated class is expected to handle the same range of instantiations as the templated version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first thing is making it clear what the meaning of the question is. If the question is whether the objects of the type are going to be larger (i.e. `sizeof(T<int>) > sizeof(T_int)`) then the answer is *no*. If the question is about the binary footprint of the application itself, including the code for the functions, then the answer is that the overall size of the program might actually be smaller in the case of a template as only *used* member functions will be compiled (unless explicitly instantiated). Although at the end of the day, the linker could potentially discard unused members from the non-template version also.

There is a common term: *code bloat* that is used to refer to the explosion of code generated by templates. The term refers to the fact that each different instantiation of a template will generate its own functions, and that can cause more functions to be present in the executable than having a smaller set of non-template functions for which conversions of the arguments are allowed.

Consider a possible interface for a vector template:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector {
   template <typename U> void push_back(U u);
//....
```

For every call to `push_back` with a different argument type, a new function will be generated, so there will be a function for `Vector<int>::push_back('a')` and another one for `Vector<int>::push_back(1)`. Compare that with the interface of `std::vector` in which the member function is not a template and the caller does the type conversion.

While this can be a source of larger executables, I don't consider this to be what was asked for. In particular, for a templated type, and the equivalent non-template type handcrafted for the particular instantiated type, the generated code should be equivalent (ignoring the fact that mangled names tend to be larger for templates :))

Comment: @Nawaz: I just dumped what came to mind considering the final executable (in the intermediate level, for a template the code before linking might have multiple definitions of exactly the same member functions in each translation unit, but those get discarded at link time). If you have something else in mind to complete the *almost all*, I am interested in hearing them :)

Comment: No. I don't have anything else in my mind. You said pretty much everything I could think of (as of now). I said "almost all" for exactly the same reason I did not say "all". I think it is wise to be open to possibilities. :-)

Comment: @didierc: The mangling comment is just a joke... don't take it seriously. You can always call the template 'X' and make it shorter!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is NO, as far as memory is concerned. I mean, it does not necessarily has to take more memory, though some evil guy might write a class template just to prove *his* point that class template version takes more memory.

However, the source code of the class template could be bigger (or lesser for that matter) than a non-template clas versions for a particular value(s) of the type parameter(s).

```
template<typename T>
struct point_t
{
    T x, y, z;
};

struct point_int
{
    int x, y, z;
};

std::cout << (sizeof(point_int) == sizeof(point_t<int>)) << std::end;
```

It will print `true` (or `1`).

Note only that the memory layout of `point_int` and `point_t<int>` will be same. So you can even cast like this:

```
point_t<int>  pt {10, 20, 30};

point_int  pi = *reinterpret_cast<point_int*>(&pt);

std::cout << "{" << pi.x <<"," << pi.y <<"," << pi.z << "}" << std::endl;
```

It will print `{10, 20, 30}`.

- [Online Demo](http://ideone.com/JsWc0g)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The template is replaced with the real values in every place it is refrenced at compile time.
so if you have a template class say:

```
public List<T>
{
  public T* MyT;
  ...
}
```

and your code uses it with a specific type say:
List , than what is actually happening that
this code is used:

```
public List<Point>
{
public Point *MyT;
....
}
```

So it is essantially the same size as any other non-template class.